# css to mimic a simple bar chart

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create this with css and having a hard time getting it to align correctly.  I am just trying to fill a box that starts at middle point of a div and have its height equal to the percentage.  If it gets over a certain percentage I want it to be inside the filled div.  Guessing this is not that hard but I can't seem to figure it out.  Mainly how to get the fill box to start half way down and either fill up or down depending on positive or negative.

I would appreciate any help.

[image]

jsbin link

http://jsbin.com/lexifetuja/edit?html,css,js,output

```
.col-sm-3 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height:200px;
}

.fill-box {
    background-color: #213F5E;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
}

.fill-box1 {
    height: 6%;
}

.fill-box2 {
    height: 41%;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <span class="percentage text-left">12%</span>

            <div class="fill-box fill-box1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <span class="percentage text-left">-82%</span>

            <div class="fill-box fill-box2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put your code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class for negative percentage `fill-box` elements and set the `top` position to `100px` (so that the top of the element starts at the half way point of the container) and then for the positive percentage `fill-box` just set the `top` position to negative the remaining percentage:

```css
.col-sm-3 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height:200px;
}

.fill-box {
  background-color:#213F5E;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
}
  .fill-box.negative {
    top:100px;
  }

.fill-box1 {
  height:6%;
  transform:translateY(-94%);
}

.fill-box2 {
  height:41%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <span class="percentage text-left">12%</span>

            <div class="fill-box fill-box1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <span class="percentage text-left">-82%</span>

            <div class="fill-box fill-box2 negative"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I made a couple of tweaks to move the percentage but thanks for getting me there.  http://jsbin.com/hizeriloqu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Glad you got it figured out, happy to help!